# Magic getter/setter not being called

Tags: php, oop, echo

When I was reading the OOP chapter in the Zend PHP Certification study guide, 5.5, I found a question that gave me a shock from its answer. This question is:

```
class Magic
{
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = array( "a" => "A" , "b" => "B" , "c" => "C" );
    protected $c = array( 1 , 2 , 3 );

    public function __get( $v )
    {
        echo "$v";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }

    public function __set( $var , $val )
    {
        echo "$var: $val,";
        $this->$var = $val;
    }
}

$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . ", ";
$m->c = "CC";
echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . ", ";
```

The output for this code is:

```
b, c, A, B, C, c: CC, b, c, A, B, C
```

Why does this code not print `a`, and how does it work?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did they really write `echo "$v";` in a text book?

Comment: you have `public $a` property, getter not works here )

Comment: other question is magic: `who prints extra commas and spaces?`

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Yes I write the code as is in the book!

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [here's the code](https://eval.in/225002) that gives the exact result shown by the OP/given in the book.

Comment: @raina77ow: Wow, that's some messed up debugging output. [Here's an edit that makes it much clearer what's really happening.](https://eval.in/225078)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__get` is only invoked for non-existent or invisible properties. In other words, when you write

```
$obj->prop
```

if `prop` is defined and is visible in the current context, it will be returned "as is", without calling `__get`.

Example:

```
class X {

    public   $pub = 1;
    private  $pri = 2;

    function __get($v) {
        echo "[get $v]\n";
        return 42;
    }

    function test() {
        echo $this->foo, "\n";  // __get invoked
        echo $this->pri, "\n";  // no __get
        echo $this->pub, "\n";  // no __get

    }
}

$x = new X;
$x->test();

echo $x->foo, "\n"; // __get invoked
echo $x->pri, "\n"; // __get invoked (property not visible)
echo $x->pub, "\n"; // no __get
```

This explains why `magic->a` doesn't invoke the getter. Now, since you also have the setter defined, `magic->c = CC` actually changes the *protected* member of the class, therefore, when you echo `magic->c` later on, this still invokes the getter (due to `c`'s invisibility), and the getter returns `this->b[c]`, not the actual value of `this->c`.

Here's your code, slightly rewritten for clarity:

```
class Magic
{
    public $a = "publicA";
    protected $values = array( "a" => "valA" , "b" => "valB" , "c" => "valC" );
    protected $c = "oldC";

    public function __get( $v )
    {
        echo "[get $v]\n";
        return $this->values[$v];
    }

    public function __set( $var , $val )
    {
        echo "[set $var=$val]\n";
        $this->$var = $val;
    }
}

$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . "\n";
$m->c = "newC";
echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . "\n";
```

Results:

```
[get b]      
[get c]
publicA, valB, valC  # no getter for `a` 
[set c=newC]
[get b]
[get c]              # getter still invoked for `c`
publicA, valB, valC  # no getter for `a`
```

#### An exercise to the reader:

Why is the output different if you replace dots `.` in the echo statements with commas:

```
$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a , ", " , $m->b , ", " , $m->c , "\n";
$m->c = "newC";
echo $m->a . ", " , $m->b , ", " , $m->c , "\n";
```

Comment: You say `it will be returned "as is"` but why its not print the value of `$a`

Comment: It does (it's `A`), just _after_ all the magic methods are done with their own printing.

Comment: @georg A brilliant exercise. ) When reading the question, I actually misread dots for commas - and wondered why `echo` had to wait. )

Comment: @raina77ow: yes, the code in the question requires one to understand both get/set stuff and evaluation order.

Comment: Someone upvoted this, and I was curious enough to check. Now, five years later, I have _absolutely_ no clue what this is all about ;o)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, here's what gets printed ([**demo**](https://eval.in/224991)):

```
bcA, B, C, c: CC,bcA, B, C,
```

The point is, each part of `$m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . ", "` expression is evaluated BEFORE the result will be printed by `echo`. In this case, there's a side effect of such evaluation.

*As @georg demonstrated, that would have been rather different if the code were written as `echo $m->a, ', ', $m->b, ', ', $m->c, ', '` instead: in that case, each operand would have been sent to output immediately after its evaluation!*

`$m->a` part is easy to evaluate, as `a` is a public property; its value is string `'A'`.

`$m->b` part, however, is a tricky one: `b` is a protected property, hence magic method `__get()` is to be called. This method prints `b` (the name of the property accessed) and returns `B` (value of `$this->b['b']`). That's why you see your line starting with `b` - it's printed before the whole expression is evaluated!

The same happens with `$m->c`, as `c` is also a protected property: the getter itsels prints `c`, but returns `C` (value of `$this->b['c']`), which will be printed as part of the whole expression.

After that `$m->c = "CC"` line is processed, calling another - setter - magic method (as `c` is protected, remember). This method is what prints `c: CC,`, as `$var` is equal to the name of the property to be set, and `$val` is its new value (passed into `__set`).

But even though magic setter eventually changes the value of `c` property, the next line in the code will output the same string as before. It's because the magic getter never access `$this->c` - it returns the value of `$this->b['c']` instead, when queried for `c`.

---

The bottom line is: also the certification guides and various similar-flavoured tests love magic methods, in the real code it's better avoid them unless you really know what you're going to get. ) Usually these things are hidden deep within the frameworks' cores, serving as engines for high-level abstraction; it's very rare that you need to provide yet another level of high-level abstraction over that one.

Comment: The output I write is the answer in the book there is no free text its multiple choose question!

Answer (score 2):

The output you got does not match what I got:

```
bcA, B, C, c: CC,bcA, B, C,
```

Nevertheless, this class is demonstrating [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) via the [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get()` and `__set()` which you may have come across. I think the reason for your confusion may be the order in which the letters came out.

Since the `__get()` magic method contains an `echo` of the actual property name, you **could** have gotten `abc` had it not been for this small detail:

```
/**  Overloading is not used on declared properties.  */
public $a = "A";
```

Thus, since the expression does **not** access the magic method for property `a`, it will **not** print the property *name*, instead, it prints the *value*. Take note of the order the `echo` functions are executed. The `echo` in the getter magic method is executed before the echo outside of the class.

Note:

> PHP's interpretation of "overloading" is different than most object
>   oriented languages. Overloading traditionally provides the ability to
>   have multiple methods with the same name but different quantities and
>   types of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your __get method in the class. It is always triggering the get method and calling `$b` array values.

```
public function __get( $v )
{
    echo "$v";
    return $this->b[$v];
}
```

Every time when you are calling `$m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . ", ";`  it's triggering the __get method and displaying the key pair value.

Similarly,

```
$m->c = "CC";
```

is triggering the __set method and displaying the set value.

```
public function __set( $var , $val )
{
    echo "$var: $val,";
    $this->$var = $val;
}

echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b . ", " . $m->c . ", ";
```

Now again the __get method is triggered and displaying the key pair value.

Comment: Actually it's not triggering the __get method for public properties as `$m->a`. See the other answers for proper explanation.